# How do I install windows from Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, boot, bootable-media

Recently I installed linux mint 17.1 in my Samsung laptop. But now I am unable to boot Windows and whenever I put live usb at startup it goes straight to the grub bootloader and doesn't show anything and and it starts loading Linux Mint, and I dont find any boot devices on the boot menu please help me? Is there any process to install Windows directly from linux without usb or CD?

Answer (score 0):

If you are booting from Live USB, you are only booting what is on the USB, which appears to be Linux Mint.  You need to remove the USB and boot from your hard drive.

You probably installed GRUB bootloader when you installed Linux Mint, and if you boot from the regular hard drive instead of the Live USB, when GRUB loads, it should give you a choice of which OS to boot from.